# jQuery ajax error on success

Tags: jquery, json, api, mustache

I've been messing around with Mustache.js & the Github api & have run into a little snag when I try to load more results that actually aren't available. My hope was to show a message or throw an error when this happens but it does not work.

Take a look at http://jsbin.com/upohuz/4/edit to see where I'm at because I'm sure its a simple fix or something that I've overlooked.

The error I get when I try to load items that aren't available is:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
```

which pertains to line 59 of the example:

```
$(html).appendTo('#foo');
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write

```
$('#foo').append(html);
```

It will not throw any errors on empty html.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. I can't believe I didn't think to try it... I guess I just assumed that your solution & mine were basically the same thing...

Comment: Now, what would be nice is if I could get the error function to work now. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The error function inside $.ajaxSettings. Why is it not being fired?

Comment: Error function invokes on error. Error json parsing, bad header etc. Empty string or null in response is not error.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. So what do I do instead then?

Comment: Just check response for empty string or null